# Como colocar apóstrofos simples e concatenar com uma string?

Tags: java, sql

Estou com uma dúvida, eu quero poder concatenar um String, de forma que ela seja interpretada com apóstrofos simples entre ela.

Por exemplo, o SQL seria assim:

`SELECT IDALUNO, NOME, DATANASCIMENTO FROM ALUNO WHERE DATANASCIMENTO BETWEEN '07/03/1997' AND '10/03/2018';`

O que eu quero, é que no lugar das datas `'07/03/1997' AND '10/03/2018'` eu consiga colocar duas variáveis do tipo string.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT IDALUNO, NOME, DATANASCIMENTO FROM ALUNO WHERE DATANASCIMENTO BETWEEN 'dataInicial' AND 'dataFinal';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, você não colocou muita coisa ai, se eu entendi bem, tudo o que tem a fazer, seria algo como:

```
"SELECT IDALUNO, NOME, DATANASCIMENTO FROM ALUNO WHERE DATANASCIMENTO BETWEEN '" + dataInicial + "' AND '" + dataFinal + "'";
```

Comment: Essa estratégia de concatenação de Strings fica sujeita a ataques de *SQL Injection*, a não ser que você possa garantir `dataInicial` e `dataFinal` foram devidamente sanitizadas recomendo o uso de `PreparedStatement`conforme [a resposta do Carlos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/284995/100)

Answer (score 4):

Use `PreparedStatment` e `?` para as 'variáveis' como em:

```
Date dataInicial = ...;             // java.sql.Date
Date dataFinal = ...;
String query = "SELECT IDALUNO, NOME, DATANASCIMENTO "
    + "FROM ALUNO WHERE DATANASCIMENTO BETWEEN ? AND ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query)) {
    stmt.setDate(1, dataInicial);
    stmt.setDate(2, dataFinal);
    try (ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Dessa forma não existe dependência de como a data é apresentada/formatada.

*Note que a classe `Date` é do pacote `java.sql` e não a do `java.util`!*

Comment: A partir do Java 8 uma alternativa ao uso de `java.sql.Date` é combinar  objetos do pacote `java.time` (e.g., `LocalDate`) com `stmt.setObject`. Para mais detalhes veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31238011/664577